# CSS not working while in deployment in django

Tags: python, css, django

This is my file structure

```
Project
  asgi.py
  .
  .
  .
main
  admin.py
  .
  .
  static
    css files
templates
users
  admin.py
  .
  .
  static
    files
static (created after collectstatic)
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

Static url and root

```
STATIC_URL = "/STATIC/"
STATIC_ROOT = OS.PATH.JOIN(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I did collectstatic and it works properly all files are coped to /static/ folder
now this all works fine with running with debug = true but when I set debug false none of the css loads.

example of a css in html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/style.css' %}">
```

this is happening only with any templates inside "main" app, for "users" app all the css is loading properly

Comment: Django does not serve static files in production (when `DEBUG` is `False`). What is your web server and how did you configure it?

Comment: Apache server is planned for static files and django site together, for now local host of django server itself is not showing any css files.                                  I am just using local machine with test server

Comment: That's expected. As said, django server **does not serve static files** when debug is false. It just won't do it!

Comment: But in that case none of the static files should load right? But the static files associated with the "users" app are loading alright, only the files in "main" app are not.

Comment: That's not possible, read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development). Or are you using whitenoise?

Comment: Nope no whitenoise. I'll try with server I guess then. Thanks for helping anyways.

Comment: One advice: When you see 404 errors for files in your browser, always open your developer tools and check the **actual URL** it's trying to fetch (or look at the source to figure it out). That usually tells you where the problem is.